# Square-free 2-factor in cubic graph

Tags: graph-theory

An undirected graph has square-free 2-factors if it has a 2-factor with no $C_4$ cycles. There is no known efficient algorithm that recognizes graphs with square-free 2-factors in general graphs.

I am interested in square-free 2-factors in **cubic** graphs.

> What is a smallest cubic graph that has square-free 2-factor?

Comment: I have a question about the wording of your question. Do you have reason to believe that there is a *unique* smallest cubic graph that has a square-free 2-factor? Smallest in what sense? In theory there could be various different examples which all have the same number of vertices or edges, or whichever measure you use to compare graphs.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn I have no reason. Smallest in the numbers of nodes.

Comment: Okay, that works. So the question is "What is *a* smallest cubic graph that has square-free 2-factor?". I'll think about it, but I also have to leave in a few minutes, so don't expect an answer from me straight away. In any case, sorry for nitpicking. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $3$-prism $K_2 \square C_3$. The square-free $2$-factor consists of the two copies of $K_3$. This is clearly minimal.

Comment: $C_6$ is also a $2$-factor (also square free)

Comment: @Joffan Ah, indeed it is.